# Is it possible to use vimgrep for a visual selection of the current file?

Tags: search, vim, vimgrep

I would like to search with vimgrep only within a visual selection of the current file and not the whole file. Is that possible and how? I couldn't find something for this case with Google or in vim help.

The reason why I want this is because I need the result in the quicklist (`copen`) and `:g/FOO` which is showing the matching lines at the bottom is not doing this job.

Comment: You need implement the "only within a visual selection" part by yourself. http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Search_using_quickfix_to_list_occurrences  here you can find how to search pattern in current file and put in qflist. what you could do is writing a wrapper function, save the range of the `'< and '>`, after qflist was filled, you filter the entries, remove the entries outside the selection range. I think it won't be too complicated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you can, as Vim has special regular expression *atoms* for mark positions, and the start and end of the visual selection is marked by `'<` and `'>`. As there are atoms for on / before / after a mark, we need to combine those to cover the entire range of selected lines:

On the selection start `|` after the selection start and before the selection end `|` on the selection end.

To limit the search to the current file, the special `%` keyword is used.

```
:vimgrep/\%(\%'<\|\%>'<\%<'>\|\%'>\)FOO/ %
```

Comment: thanks, it was exactly I was looking for and very well described so I understand the logic behind it.

Answer (score 4):

You are on the right path with using `:g` command. The basic idea is do something like this:

```
:g/FOO/caddexpr expand("%") . ":" . line(".") .  ":" . getline(".")
```

Now lets make it a command

```
command! -range -nargs=+ VisualSeach cgetexpr []|<line1>,<line2>g/<args>/caddexpr expand("%") . ":" . line(".") .  ":" . getline(".")
```

Now you can do `:VisualSearch FOO` and it will add the searches to the `quickfix` list.

Note that the issue w/ this is only finds one match per line.

Comment: thx a lot, it does the job, although I slightly prefer the solution of @Ingo as it less scripting and more worked out within the logic of vimgrep. Still thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This is from Steve Losh's vimrc.  It makes `*` work on the visual selection.  I've gotten pretty dependent on it.

```
" Visual Mode */# from Scrooloose {{{
function! s:VSetSearch()
let temp = @@
norm! gvy
let @/ = '\V' . substitute(escape(@@, '\'), '\n', '\\n', 'g')
let @@ = temp
endfunction

vnoremap * :<C-u>call <SID>VSetSearch()<CR>//<CR><c-o>
vnoremap # :<C-u>call <SID>VSetSearch()<CR>??<CR><c-o>
```

Comment: Edited to include the vnoremaps